# Creating multiple records with contextually-related data

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The application is a form of accounting entry, in this specific case entry adjustments.  The target behaviour is that a user selects a series of accounts for editing balances; however in practice the application creates new entries for each selected account, then *map* and *sum* generate balance values.

Thus the controller calls the selected accounts from a previous form

```
    @bilancinos = Bilancino.find(params[:bilancino_ids])
```

And the view invokes each account

```
<%= form_tag create_multiple_bilancinos_path, :method => :put  do %>
  <% @bilancinos.each do |bilancino| %>
    <%= fields_for "bilancinos[]", bilancino do |f| %>
```

which is great to extract the account selected

```
<%= f.hidden_field :operativo_id, :value => bilancino.operativo_id %>
```

but the amount

```
<%= f.text_field :amount, :class => "text-right" %>
```

is being derived form the source `@bilancinos` and the rendered HTML

```
<input class="text-right" id="bilancinos_1457_amount" name="bilancinos[1457][amount]" size="30" type="text" value="8325.22" />
```

is attempting to edit the existing record, which is mistaken and leads naturally to an `undefined method`stringify_keys' for "1457":String`.  The create_multiple action is defined as

```
@bilancinos = Bilancino.create(params[:bilancinos].keys, params[:bilancinos].values).reject {|p| p.errors.empty? }
```

I suspect my form's syntax is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the following manner (*keeping a trace here because most answers related to creating/saving multiple child records; this is outright creation, but with a context*).

The first controller action invokes the context-determined records

```
@bilancinos = Bilancino.find(params[:bilancino_ids])
```

While the second controller action creates the records

```
params[:new_bilancinos].each do |keys, values|
  b = Bilancino.create(values)
end
```

The form is created based on the context

```
<%= form_tag create_multiple_bilancinos_path, :method => :put  do %>
  <% @bilancinos.each do |bilancino| %>
```

and the values are generated with the following syntax

```
    <%= hidden_field_tag "new_bilancinos[#{bilancino.id}][cdg_id]", bilancino.cdg_id %>
    <%= text_field_tag "new_bilancinos[#{bilancino.id}][amount]", "0", class: "text-right" %>
    <%= select_tag "new_bilancinos[#{bilancino.id}][natura_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(Natura.order("id DESC").all, "id", "nome", {:selected => 1 }) %>
```

where the bilancino.id is *practically* only a unique key set as a placeholder for rails handling.  New bilancino records are created with their own IDs.